# Printing column 2 and 4 of file using an input delimiter in c

Tags: c

I've been trying to figure out how to print the contents any file from stdin in column 2 and 4 with ',' being the input delimiter (using c).

For example, if the file's contents were:

```
abcd,55555,string,22222
```

it would print to stdout:

```
55555,22222,
```

I'm not sure why it prints blank

Comment: Please use a more orthodox C indentation style — I strongly recommend either Allman (it's what I use, more or less) or 1TBS (which is used by many other people).  See Wikipedia on [Indentation Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) for the variants.  Your code in `valueinarr()` seems to be related to Pico style — which may be common when programming in Pico but is not an accepted style for C code.

Comment: _Side note:_ `for (int count=0;  count<(strlen(word));  count++)` does N**2 character scans. That's because `strlen` has to rescan the _entire_ string on each loop iteration. Better to do (e.g) `int len = strlen(word); for (int count=0;  count<len;  count++)` This only does N*2 scans.

Comment: `col` will be reset to `1` on _each_ loop. (i.e. it will never progress beyond 2). Maybe you want to move `int col = 1;` under the `while` [instead of under the `for`].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting in a wrong way, mainly. Also there are some bad practices out there in your code, so I took some freedom to do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int valueinarr(int val,int arr[])
{
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
        if (val==arr[j])
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int arr[2]={2,4};
    char word[101];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = freopen(0,"r",stdin);


    while(fscanf(fp,"%[^\n]\n",word)!=EOF)
    {

        int col=1;

        for(int count=0;count<(strlen(word));count++)
        {
            if(valueinarr(col,arr))
            {
                printf("%c",word[(count)]);
            }
            if(word[count]==',') col++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Although this code will solve your problems with input in some expected format, I must say: this code IS BAD in many ways that are not of part of your question.

Comment: I edited it so that it doesn't contain anything unnecessary.

Comment: Do you know how I could replace the input delimiter with output delimiter so that it prints 2222.4444

Answer (score 2):

[@Astormooke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2977631/astormooke) is right about progressing `col` - since you need to consider the case where `valueinarr(col, arr)` returns false.

But another issue I foresee is your declaration for `col` - this should go outside of the `for` loop, otherwise you'll just be resetting it each time.

Answer (score 1):

Just glancing at your code, it appears that the control flow will never make it to

```
col++
```

if

```
col != 2 or col != 4
```

With that, we see since it starts as 1 you will never make it to your print statement.

Comment: Also, if I read the code correctly, on each iteration of the loop, `int col = 1;` is executed, which also prevent `col` from getting bigger than `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to solve this using a simple approach, you can use `strtok()` function and a `counter` to output what you want:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int counter;
    char word[101] = "\0";
    char *token = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen("abc.txt", "r");
    
    if(!fp)
    {
        perror("abc.txt: ");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    while(fscanf(fp, " %[^\n]\n", word) != EOF)
    {
        printf("Contents: %s\n", word);
        counter = 1;
        token = strtok(word, ",");
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            if(counter == 2 || counter == 4)
                printf("Col %d: %s\n", counter, token);
            counter++;
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Contents: 3333,44444,55555,88888,111111
Col 2: 44444
Col 4: 88888
```

Comment: Still, the fscanf used is a bug in itself. Try just adding an extra newline at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @DarioRodriguez Indeed! But this bug can be removed by just putting a whitespace before `%[^\n]\n`. Like **" %[^\n]\n"**.

Comment: It will indeed eat whitespaces fine, but the code is still buggy. Long lines in the file will make it crash. I suppose that `fscanf(fp, " %100[^\n]%c", word, &endc)` with `char endc` declared, and then check this character to be `\n`, because long lines will split.

Comment: Also, in GNU environments, memory can be dynamically allocated with `m` format specifier to avoid such a bug. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Last: I would rather avoid `char word[101]="\0"` here... it is just useless. If you don't trust fscanf to put '\0' at the end, you should `memset (word, 0, WORD_SIZE)` before every call instead, and if you trust fscanf well, you know, just relax.

Comment: @DarioRodriguez I initialize every variable that I declare(mostly). It's just because it assures me that I will not get any garbage value accidentally in the program and it's not a bad habit I guess. Although, I will consider `memset()`.